# Swift3: Why this simple block of code takes ages to compile

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I spent a lot of time with the build report only to figure out why compiling in Xcode 8.2.1 with Swift3 takes so long.

One issue i found is a simple override init function with simple content taking about 45 seconds to type-check/compile.

I cannot figure out what is the cause. I tried to split up into functions, provided types where needed, but still it takes ages to compile.

Superclass MyScene is inherting from SKScene just having one function calling removeAllActions on the scene.

Heres the code:

```
class LevelSelectionScene: MyScene {
  var gameMode:GameMode
  var levelSelectionLayer:SKNode!
  var screenSize:CGSize!
  var startingPoint:CGPoint!
  var backButton: Button!
  fileprivate var _buttonBg : SKSpriteNode!
  fileprivate var _layerTouched : Bool = false
  fileprivate var _touchPress : Bool = false

  override init(size: CGSize) {
    self.screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    self.gameMode = GameMode.Classic
    let tileGap:CGFloat = Constants.Config.LevelSelection.tilegap
    let tileWidth:CGFloat = Constants.Config.LevelSelection.tilewidth
    let numX:CGFloat = screenSize.width / (tileWidth+tileGap)
    self.levelSelectionLayer = SKNode()
    self.levelSelectionLayer.zPosition = 100
    self.startingPoint = CGPoint(x: (-numX*(tileWidth+tileGap))/2+tileWidth/2+tileGap, y: 0)
    super.init(size: size)
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift's compiler is very slow when it comes to figuring out types when you're mixing and matching a lot. The culprit here is the math happening for `self.startingPoint`. It's having to do some work with those `2`s there.

Here's a nice example you can throw into a blank project.

```
class LevelSelectionScene {

    init(size: CGSize) {
        let screenSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 480)
        let tileGap: CGFloat = 10
        let tileWidth: CGFloat = 10
        let numX: CGFloat = screenSize.width / (tileWidth + tileGap)

        // let slowPoint = CGPoint(x: (-numX*(tileWidth+tileGap))/2+tileWidth/2+tileGap, y: 0)

        let fastPoint = CGPoint(x: (-numX * (tileWidth + tileGap)) / CGFloat(2) + tileWidth / CGFloat(2) + tileGap, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Try compiling this and notice how fast it is. Then remove the `//` for `slowPoint` and notice how slow it is. Whenever you're doing math in swift be as explicit as you can about the types.

TL;DR turn those `2`s into `CGFloat(2)`s for `self.startingPoint`.